# vertical-align:middle when multiple elements are in the parent

Tags: css

How do I vertically center both the `img` and the following text inside the `td`?

```
<td><a><img width="32" height="32" alt="txt" src="txt.png">Text</a></td>
```

I've experimented with `vertical-align:middle;` but haven't been successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify vertical alignment on the elements inside the table cell.  In your case:

```
td a, td img { vertical-align:middle; }
```

Or see http://jsfiddle.net/ZfP7r/1/.

Comment: Thanks Katie,  I wasn't targetting the img.  Just curious, why is it necessary?

Comment: Check out the spec for vertical-align: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align.  It's for aligning the **selected element** against the table cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired effect by placing the text inside a `span` tag.  Then position this `span` as required and add a `line-height` with `vertical-align:middle;`

This should produce the desired effect - http://jsfiddle.net/tdJ8u/23/